# How to store an associative array in a table

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to create a polling system where if the user goes on a question, that question is logged in the table's question_arr column. The question's id and the user's answer will be logged. So for example, the array will look something like this `"1"=>"0","3"=>"0","8"=>"1"` how do I store the array in my table?

The array will be searched to check which choice the user answered if he/she returned to that question.

Comment: Would it not be more efficient to use another DB table and normalization - by storing an array in one column you are  storing 2 values in a column that can be in 2 separate tables , for instance users and user_answers.

Comment: @Daniel_ZA Are you saying to create two columns, one for the question id's and the other for the answers?

Answer (score 0):

To save the log create another table like `qua_ans_log` with columns `userId`, `questionId` and `answer` and insert the values one by one. This will be more helpful for your db operations than using a single column to save all values.

Comment: Would these columns be arrays?

Comment: Would the columns store one value or multiple values (arrays)?

Comment: Only one value. 
For eg 1st row : 1, 1, A
2nd row : 1,2,D
3rd row : 1,3,B etc

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster and more optimized if the columns stored arrays instead though?

Comment: @user2896120 It'll surely be faster to store initially, but the way your DB structure stands right now, it is not normalized. So, if you were to retrieve the results of a specific index from within an array stored as a single column, the logic required to do so will be more cumbersome than the efforts required to normalize the tables.